# 401 Unauthorized Error while login into nexus docker registry

Tags: docker, nexus3

I am using nexus as a Docker container, with tag sonatype/nexus3:3.14.0. Also, I connect nexus with LDAP for user better user management it is helpful for group and role management.

For my case, I create a blog-store and create two docker registry repository, one hosted and one group.   I try to log in, on hosted and it works fine. But when I tried to connect into the grouped repository I get 
401 Unauthorized. I also tried to connect with admin credentials but I get the same error too,

> Error response from daemon: login attempt to https:///v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized.

Suggestions are welcome
PParthenis

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Enable the `Docker Bearer Token Realm` in Nexus Security->Realms Tab.

As stated in [here](https://community.sonatype.com/t/docker-login-401-unauthorized/1345/6)

Answer (score 5):

In my case **Docker Bearer Token Realm** security realm was already enabled. But prioritizing this realm did the trick.

If **Docker Bearer Token Realm** is already enabled in Nexus Security->Realms Tab, Increase its priority.

For more info https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/user-authentication/realms